# multiple sounds on different mouseovers

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I am finding trouble with multiple mousovers with different sounds.

trouble: when i do a mousover on Rockbutton it will play the song of Popaudio. Is there a better way or a simple solution for this? Many thanks!

```
    // Muziekje Rock --------------------------------------------------Muziekje rock
    document.getElementById("RockButton").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
    function mouseOver() { 
        document.getElementById('RockDanceAudio').play();
    }
    function mouseOut() { 
      document.getElementById('RockDanceAudio').pause();
    }




       document.getElementById("PopButton").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
    function mouseOver() { 
        document.getElementById('PopAudio').play();
    }
    function mouseOut() { 
      document.getElementById('PopAudio').pause();
    }



<!-- Pagina3 Tatjana                                  PaginaDrieTatjana-->
    <div id="PaginaDrieTatjana" style="display:none;">
      <h1>Kies soort dans</h1>

      <div id="Rock">
        <h3>Rock Dance</h3>
        <img src="Tatjana/Een.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="RockButton">
            <p>Kiezen</p>
            <audio id="RockDanceAudio" src="rock_audio.mp3"></audio>
        </div>
      </div >

      <div id="Pop">
        <h3>Pop Dance</h3>
        <img src="Tatjana/Twee.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="PopButton">
            <p>Kiezen</p>
            <audio id="PopAudio" src="pop_audio.mp3"></audio>
        </div>
```

Comment: Rename your mouseOver functions to mouseOverRock and mouseOverPop. You will also need to change the mouseOut events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting mouseOut and mouseOver functions, try this:

```
var rockButton = document.getElementById("RockButton");
rockButton.onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById('RockDanceAudio').pause();
};
rockButton.onmouseover = function() { 
    document.getElementById('RockDanceAudio').play();
};


var popButton = document.getElementById("PopButton");
popButton.onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById('PopAudio').pause();
};
popButton.onmouseover = function() { 
    document.getElementById('PopAudio').play();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you're overwriting your initial mouseOut() function later on redefining it to play PopAudio.

That means that when the mouseout event happens, only the latter is played.

This is because the function is evaluated only when the event actually happens.

To prevent this, use different names for the functions:

```
document.getElementById("RockButton").onmouseout = function() {mouseOutRock()};
function mouseOutRock() { 
  document.getElementById('RockDanceAudio').pause();
}

document.getElementById("PopButton").onmouseout = function() {mouseOutPop()};
function mouseOutPop() { 
  document.getElementById('PopAudio').pause();
}
```

of even better use anonymous functions:

```
document.getElementById("RockButton").onmouseout = function() { 
  document.getElementById('RockDanceAudio').pause();
}

document.getElementById("PopButton").onmouseout = function() { 
  document.getElementById('PopAudio').pause();
}
```